find the other lines that intersect a set of evenly-spaced points along a line on a torus
i have a square, side length $2\pi$, and i'm drawing lines on it that wrap around when they reach the edges - this is of course equivalent to the surface of a torus. the lines are straight lines that pass through the origin, and they're marked at regular intervals (or equivalently, i'm marking the points $\\{(a \cdot n \mod 2\pi,\ b \cdot n \mod 2\pi)\ |\ n \in \mathbb{N}\\}$ for some $a,b$). sometimes these points line up on at least one other straight line (wrapping around the torus), and i want to find these lines where they exist. i'm also interested in lines that pass through only most of the points, but that might be more complicated.
my progress so far is pretty limited. such lines definitely sometimes exist, at least for cases with finitely many points - for instance, $(a,b) = (\pi/4,\pi/2)$ and $(a,b) = (5\pi/4,\pi/2)$ generate the same set of points:

the motivation for this, which i include mostly because it's nice to look at, relates to a system where two points rotate around a circle at different speeds with a line drawn between them at regular intervals. certain curves appear - they seem to be of the form $x = \frac{r}{r+1}sin(\theta+k) + (1-\frac{r}{r+1})sin(r\theta+k),\ y = \frac{r}{r+1}cos(\theta+k) + (1-\frac{r}{r+1})cos(r\theta+k)$. there'll be one such curve that appears in all figures with the same ratio of speeds between the two points, and every curve corresponds to some ratio (that's the $r$ in the formulae). but sometimes other curves appear too depending on the interval between the lines. i think these are aliasing effects where the lines that are drawn happen to also be lines that would be drawn for a different ratio. since each line is drawn between two points on the edge of a circle, they can be plotted as points on a $2\pi$ by $2\pi$ square with the two angles as coordinates, and straight lines on this diagram correspond to the points moving at speeds with a fixed ratio.

(note the clear ring of spikes, which corresponds to the ratio 2:17, but also the less clear inset ring which appears only at this particular instance of that ratio (1.041 by 0.88485), and the vague ring further out where each spike is formed only of three or four lines likewise)
